# Adjust size of clustering icon in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, clustering

In my leaflet application, I would like to reduce the size of cluster icons by half and also modify the font size of the value inside of the icon:

[image]

Having read the [documentation](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) on github, I have tried changing values under `iconSize` in the `iconCreateFunction`:

```
return new L.DivIcon({ 
  html: '<div><span>' + childCount + '</span></div>', 
  className: 'marker-cluster' + c, 
  iconSize: new L.Point(40, 40) 
});
```

But this does not appear to change anything.  Is there a known workaround for changing the size of cluster icons and their text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `iconSize` option controls the size of the *container* DOM element for the icon/divicon. The actual visible size depends on the CSS rules applied to the container and the contents.

Look at the [default CSS rules applied to your cluster markers](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/master/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css#L44): they contain hard-coded sizes in pixels, which are applied regardless of the size of the container.

Comment: strangely, changing width and height under `marker-cluster div` has no effect